# Laravel, reset password

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

this is my App/user.php file:

```
    namespace App;

    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
    use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;
    use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthenticatableContract;
    use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\CanResetPassword as CanResetPasswordContract;
    class user extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract, CanResetPasswordContract
    {
        //
        use Authenticatable, CanResetPassword;

        public function session(){
            return $this->hasMany("App\session", "userid", "userid");
        }
    }
```

the error returned:
FatalErrorException in user.php line 12:
Trait 'App\CanResetPassword' not found

Help me!

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to add `use Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\CanResetPassword;` to the block of other `use` statements at the top of the file.